# Embeded Firebird Database and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, firebird

I am trying to use the Firebird embeded DB together with Hibernate, but I get the following error when trying to create the database:

```
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544344. I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "D:\DB\FIREBIRD.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
null
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:123)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractDriver.connect(AbstractDriver.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "D:\DB\FIREBIRD.FDB"
Error while trying to open file
null
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.jni.JniGDSImpl.native_isc_attach_database(Native Method)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.jni.BaseGDSImpl.iscAttachDatabase(BaseGDSImpl.java:158)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:105)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:490)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:69)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:120)
    ... 36 more
```

What I have done until now:

1. I've set the hibernate configuration.
   Driver = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver",
   Dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect",
   Url = "jdbc:firebirdsql:embedded:D:\DB\FIREBIRD.FDB",
2. I have added the **jaybird-full** jar to my classpath.
3. I have added **jaybird22.dll**, **fbembed.dll** (the whole folder) to my path.

The dlls seem to be loaded since if I delete the dlls I get and exception telling me that **jaybird22.dll** cannot be found.

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: I assume D:\DB exists and you have the permission to create files in it. try jdbc:firebirdsql:embedded:D:/DB/FIREBIRD.FDB. Can you use the database without using hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the step I was missing was creating the database file manually:

```
FBManager manager = new FBManager(GDSType.getType("EMBEDDED"));
manager.start();
manager.createDatabase(myDbFile, username, password);
manager.stop();
```